What size should my inside-out planets be so that people on the surface can see the curvature?
The universe is filled with a fluid, and people live on the inside surface of planets. I want planets to be roughly Earth-size or larger (maybe up to 3x), but I want to make sure people on the surface can see the curvature and understand that they're inside a thing.
I'm imagining a problem where the atmosphere prevents people from seeing the initial part of the curvature on the "horizon", and they'll only be able to see the surface above them after the look up past a certain angle. I don't want this to be the case.
My question is: What's the maximum planet size I can get away with and still be able to see the full curvature of the planet while standing on the surface?
Some details that might be relevant:

Planets are the nests and reproductive organs of a very large species who live inside the planets and swim around the upper atmosphere and the empty space in the center of the planet, occasionally exchanging nutrients or whatever with the "core".
The planet has lots of bioluminescence, but the main source of light is all those creatures swimming around the upper atmosphere (a few thousand of them per planet). They burn with a dim star-like light, and they travel in packs/schools. Daytime is whenever the star-creatures are above your location, and is quite irregular.
There is no gravity in the physics of this universe, but the cores of planets do exert a massive outward force, which is how planets form and how people are bound to the surface.
Planets do have an atmosphere similar to ours, which gets thinner and eventually ends when moving "up" away from the surface of the planet. Multiple gases, moisture, weather, everything you'd expect in an atmosphere. The center of the sphere is a vacuum.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If there’s a massive outward force, there might also be massive columns of rock/stareater-flesh/whatever that connects the surface to the core and prevents the crust from being blasted out into space. Such things would be visible from virtually anywhere.

I have edited the question to be more clear, I hope.

@controlgroup The pressure of the fluid that fills the universe is what keeps the planet together, along with the fact that this force tapers off over distance like gravity does in our universe. However there are massive columns between the upper layer and lower layer of the planet surface.

What's the source of light? How bright is it?

I assumed that of the Sun for my answer, but based on my info I think it doesn’t really matter much.

Since you're already in the realm of magic, just make sure your air doesn't get all blue and opaque until the diameter of the planet, or a fraction of it, and settle there. You are allowed already to declare atmospheric conditions as you see fit, including infinite view range through it, just declare that the planet's inhabitants do see the curvature at an angle of alpha, and don't see the surface in zenith, that's all.

Technically ~6,000km across, but efficially, much bigger is fine
On a cloudless summer solstice day at noon, about 75% of the solar energy reaches the earth's surface at an intensity of ~100,000lux.  In door lighting is only 100-500 lux which is bright enough to illuminate contrast when competing with sunlight.  Humans can technically see in sub 1lux lighting, but not when there is a significant other source of light; so, in daylight, we can probably see significant contrast at about 100lux allowing us to see through the atmosphere to the curvature of the world as long as about 0.1% of the sun's light is reflected through the atmosphere.
Using this, we can estimate how many atmospheres we can see through on a clear day using the equation (0.75)^(n−1) = 0.001 which gives use about 25 atmospheres.  That said, the atmosphere is much thicker near the ground than high up; so, most light scattering happens in the bottom 5km meaning that if you want to see ~125km laterally without seeing a hazy line, the Earth's slope will need to rise at least 5 km in that distance.
We now use this handy trig diagram to find the radius of that circle.

\$crd = 125 and \$versin = 5; so, we use the Pythagorean theorem to find that \$sin = 124.89996. Then we use arcsins and angle translation rules to determine that \$theta = 2.292deg.  Now knowing \$theta and \$sin we use the law of cosines to determine that the radius of the circle is 3,123km or a diameter of 6,246km.
Now that said, 6,246km is the range at which you get no hazy line at all (on a cloudless day), but as you make this planet bigger, that line will only be a very thin band that floats slightly above the horizon line and you will still see the horizon curve up towards this line so you will still know that the horizon is curving up even if it is obscured at some point. So, if your planet had a diameter similar to Earth, you'd see about 1 degree of rise before it fades into this thin blotted out band.  This means you'd see about 2 sun widths of the planet's curvature which would still be plenty to be able to tell that the shape of the world before you reach the line is a bowl which even basic logic will be enough to tell people that the world is a contiguous curve, even if this thin ring of it is hidden.
To make the haze appear close enough to the horizon to fool the naked eye, a planet would have to be several Earth diameters wide. But even if the planet were for example ~8 Earth diameters wide, then the surface would appear essentially flat fading off into a distant haze, though the shape of the sky might be telling enough to still be able to determine that they live in a globe. Because of something called Normal Reflection, we are able to tell when an object is curved, even when the whole surface receives the same amount of light; so, even if the globe were millions of km across, light would reflect in such a way that the sky itself would not appear flat.

The normal answer
Consider that we can see the surface of the illuminated Moon pretty clearly (citation needed). That distance is on average 384,00-385,000 kilometers depending on who you ask. If we assume that the creatures are illuminating the inner surface of the planet with the same intensity as the Sun (our Sun, I mean) is illuminating the surfaces of the Earth and Moon, then you’ll see that a planet of that diameter will be such that one side can see the other (if the core isn’t in the way). This will make the large-scale structure of the planet obvious. It’s also clear that if you can resolve the opposite side of the planet with your eyes, you can see the part immediately surrounding you that would alert you to the planet’s curvature.
Anything larger than that would be pretty mechanically iffy…
The better answer
…but this is already fantasy, so screw mechanics. We can fine-tune the universe’s fluid pressure later to match our planets.
This logic we just used actually applies to things more distant than the Moon, too. You know what else is illuminated by the Sun such that it is visible at night (and whose details are easily seen - even by an amateur like myself - through a telescope)? Saturn. The second-largest planet is a whopping 1.4 billion kilometers away on average. If it were physically larger in radius (or a sphere surrounding the Earth and Sun), we would be able to see its surface just as well as we can see the surface of it now.
If you’re willing to stretch even further, note that Pluto can be seen with an 8” telescope, patience, and luck. Outside that stuff starts to get too dim to see, so that seems like a reasonable upper limit: your planet has to be less than 7.5 billion kilometers in diameter for one side to be able to see the other side.
Now, knowing that we can see those celestial bodies just fine through the atmosphere even when it’s near the horizon (citation: personal experience), we can say that we’d be able to physically see curvature of the planet if the first few degrees or so (say, 10 degrees) are within 1.4 billion kilometers (or 7.5 billion if you’re willing to allow telescopes to be used). Drawing out the inscribed triacontakaihexagon (36gon), we find that the circumference of the planet is a little more than 50 billion kilometers (or 270 billion if telescopes are allowed), equation to a maximum radius of around 8 billion kilometers in radius (or around 42 billion kilometers if you allow telescopes).
There we go. Nice and big; so big in fact that you could fit the entire Solar system inside it. This is about what is expected, anyway.
Daytime would be when one of the creatures approaches the surface closely, and might last a bit longer considering the distances involved. Perhaps endow the creatures with some sort of hypersonic/orbital-speed flight, or reduce atmospheric pressure up there, so that they can make days measured in hundreds of hours or shorter.
Notes & actual application
My answer does assume that the brightness of the creatures is comparable to that of our Sun. If it’s not, you’ll want to reduce the radius of the planet. In general though, I think what we’ve established is that unles they’re really dim (certainly too dim to cause daytime unless they’re literally right above you), you can see the curvature of the planet if its radius is measured in anything smaller than tens of billions of kilometers. At that point of 42 billion kilometer radius, the area of the inner surface is $2.2\cdot10^{16}$ square kilometers, around ten billion times the Earth’s surface area of around 200 million square kilometers. Might be a bit much, so feel free to reduce the radius a bit.
The best answer
All that aside, there is a theoretical upper limit: the distance at which the light from the creatures hasn’t attenuated into invisibility. The planet itself would likely act like a massive reflector, making the surface visible anywhere the creatures are near it - effectively anywhere it’s day. If it’s day in multiple places at once, we then know that we’d be approximately able to see out to a distance of… well, however far we’re able to see star-like objects with our eyes/telescope.
So, if a group of creatures that produces “day” has luminosity similar to our Sun or maybe even much smaller, we can classify the visibility of the planet’s surface based on how far away we can see stars.
There are some nearby stars perhaps as dim as a large crowd of these creatures (depending), so the best answer I can give you would involve a distance measured in lightyears.
Given that the surface area of the planet would then be measured in square lightyears, I’m guessing we’ve gone a step too far. All this is to say “however large you want”.

I was imagining much dimmer than the sun, and a size roughly in the neighborhood of real-world planet sizes. One of the creatures by itself might be about equivalent to the moon. But your answer has me considering going big with it and doing something much larger than Earth. I think the diameter of the sun is close to the limit though, I don't want solar system sized planets.

Yeah, I’d consider that wise… It’s nice to know that light keeps going through a vacuum, but imo I would stick to making the planet around Earth-sized to Sun-sized and not much larger, because yeah eventually you’re gonna run into “too big for the story”.
